Murder movie where apartment owner is old guy with dog with a back room full of sex toys
I don't remember much about the film, but I remember this moment, where there are two (?) policemen trying to investigate a murder, and the flat-owner appears. He is an old man, with a small white (?) dog and walks snobbily through the apartment. Somebody else says something along the lines of "Don't mind him, he's weird".
Later the movie shows us the old man taking the policemen to a back room full of sex toys and rambling something about pleasures.
IIRC it is a 1980's - 1990's movie (judging by the style, I don't actually know the date). I'm pretty sure it was Hollywood, but I don't swear it. Mystery movie with some black humour I'd say.
